# Ways to significantly reduce critical mass for U235, or make U238 fissile?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, physics, nuclear

If I manage to increase the neutron generated from fission reaction by 100 times, will that reduce critical mass of U235 to 1/100?

Similarly, if I can increase neutron's energy, will it make U238 fissile?

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the neutron generated from fission"? Do you mean the size of the neutrons? If so, goodbye universe. Or do you mean increase the quantity of neutrons generated? If you mean the latter, I'd just like the point out that, that isn't how fission works...

Comment: Critical mass of a material is actually dependent on a *lot* of different attributes.  One of them is the [Neutron Multiplication Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_chain_reaction#Effective_neutron_multiplication_factor).  If you magically increased the number of neutrons being released by a single fission reaction, you would, in theory, cause more fissions than you did before.  This does not translate into a direct ratio of Increased Neutron Production to Decreased Critical Mass, since there are a myriad of other factors to consider.

Comment: You cannot change the number of neutrons (or whatever else) generated by a fission reaction anymore than you could make a water molecule to have three hydrogen with a single oxygen. Same with neutron speed (which is fixed and depends on resulting elements). U235 will adsorb *low energy* neutrons and become unstable (that's why we use some material to *slow down* neutrons emitted, in order to make them more effective). AFAIK U238 won't adsorb neutrons of any energy (speed).

Comment: Increasing number of neutrons 100x times is unrealistic. But if you wrap a piece of U235 in ideal(or near so) reflector of neutrons, then any mass would be critical :)

Comment: @Vashu That might be what I've been looking for. Do you know what's the reflection rate for the current neutron reflector? Thanks.

Comment: Berillium is typically used. It reflects less than 50% of neutrons and lowers their energy, but even so - 5 cm reflector of Be lowers plutonium critical mass from 10 to 5 kg.

Comment: @vashu So all I need is some type of barrier which deflects 100% of the neutrons, while still let out all other types of energy emitted from the fission.

Comment: With 100% any amount of uranium would go critical. But even 90% would be terrific. Though nobody knows how to do reflector so efficient. Also you don't need to worry much about letting out other types of energy. When you have some kilotons of energy concentrated in less than a liter of volume it is pretty impossible to hold it in :)

Comment: In L. Niven books there is stasis field that is impenetrable and reflects anything including neutrons. So it is used for making nuclear rocket engine - put some uranium in a bottle with very little hole, put stasis field on bottle, uranium reacts, heats up and start leaking through the hole, creating reactive force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let pretend you could increase the number of free neutrons that result from fission by a factor of 100., so instead of getting 2-3 free neutrons, you are getting 2-3 hundred (well actually 146 at most for Pu-239).

This means instead of 2 medium sized atoms as the result of fission, you are getting many very light atoms as the result of fission. What you have accomplished is that you have changed the nuclear fission event into one that requires energy, instead of one that releases energy.

You would not have critical mass no matter how much you material you had.

---

So change the physics again and make many neutrons emitted into a net energy event, Uranium would be so unstable it would all be long gone., and a lot of stable or classically stable elements would be very unstable too. Probably anything past helium or maybe carbon would be very rare, bad news all around.

---

The physics changes I refer to above involve things like changing the ratio of the strengths of the strong nulcear force and the electromagnetic force.

Re: increasing the density of your nuclear material, congratulations you have just reinvented the way modern atomic bombs work. You may have heard of implosion and gun-type nuclear weapons. Plutonium bombs are all implosion devices, you have a sub-critical mass of plutonium, then use a very carefully designed (and classified) implosion to change the bomb into a critical mass when the implosion occurs. In actual bombs, the implosion makes the plutonium about 250% as dense as it normally is. The atoms are closer together and fast super-criticality results (followed by a considerably more impressive bang).

Compressing metals is difficult, the metal very forcefully resists such compression, but the careful bomb design is good enough to get the job done.

By combining neutron reflectors, tampers, implosions, etc. modern plutonium bombs need only about 25% of the mass of plutonium required for a bare spherical mass of plutonium. If there was a method based in reality that could change the requirement significantly it would be used. Pu-239 is really expensive.

Of the common nuclear bomb materials, Pu-239 has the smallest bare-sphere critical mass (about 10 pounds), weapons grade (80% enriched) Uranium is about 60 pounds IIRC. No serious bomb-maker uses U-235, it is too hard to make (a.k.a. expensive). At the end of the Manhattan project, there was only enough weapons grade Uranium for a single bomb.

Now, Californium-252 has the lightest critical mass of anything I have seen listed, about 2.5 pounds for a bare-sphere, and presumably < 1 pound using the well-known refinements. Problem is we have only made about 8 grams of it ever (at about $27 million per gram).

If you want to ignore real world physics, you could pretend a smaller critical mass, but it would be pretend. 2.5 pounds of Pu-239 is pretty close to the real-world limit on practical bombs, and no amount of wishing changes that.

Pretending a super-explosive implosion device is just another form of hand waving. There is a pretty definite limit on the energy available from explosive compounds. You are not going to be able to compress plutonium by a factor of 5 in any sane (and thus practical) implosive bomb design. If you could, rest-assured that the guys that actually design these for real would have done so, they were smart and motivated.

Comment: I'm looking for a hypothetical way to significantly reduce critical mass. If increasing neutron's energy or quantity won't work, what about a sudden reduction of the volume? If we can pack U235 100 times denser, it should make it easier for free neutrons to hit the atom, right?

Comment: @A.Z. Yes, but there are limits on the density you can achieve. Just doubling the density requires multi-gigapascal pressures, on the order of those at Earth's core. And you need the pressure to be established in milliseconds, before fission destroys containment.

Comment: Uranium 235 has some 145 neutrons (I don't remember its Z-number, perhaps 90?), so at the most you can get those, plus 90 hydrogen ions. And as you pointed out, the process is catastrophically endothermal.

Comment: @LSerni, nice catch -- I did not even bother to point out this that 143-146 neutrons is all there is in the nucleus for U-235, U-238, Pu-239. The physics is so ridiculous you forget the obvious sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, more neutrons per fission event would lower the critical mass, but you can't really do that as the amount of neutrons released per fission is a physical property of the atoms involved and doesn't statistically change.

No, higher energy neutrons won't make something fissile.  To be [fissile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fissile_material) it has to readily absorb neutrons (lookup neutron cross section) specifically they are concerned with lower energy "thermal" neutrons that are more likely to interact with atoms, higher energy neutrons would be less likely to result in fission.

Comment: I consulted https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon

The fusion fuel of the secondary stage may be surrounded by uranium or enriched uranium, or plutonium. Fast neutrons generated by fusion can induce fission even in materials normally not prone to it, such as depleted uranium whose U-238 is not fissile and cannot sustain a chain reaction, but which is fissionable when bombarded by the high-energy neutrons released by fusion in the secondary stage.

Comment: So the question is where to get those fast neutrons.

Comment: Let's just say that the conditions in the microseconds of an active fusion explosion aren't typical for fission reactions, the shear quantity of neutrons in a small area makes some interesting things happen.  As with all nuclear reactions it's all statistical, so low probability events can happen with lots of neutrons in very a small space.

Answer (score 0):

The number of neutrons per fission event is fixed, you can't realistically get more. You can reduce critical mass by compressing the uranium but this too has limits.
What you need is some material like uobtainium or energy field that are perfect neutron reflectors.
You drill cylindrical holes in the neutron reflector, around a larger hole. Then you slam a sub-sub-critical mass of U235 in the holes. Criticality initiates in the periphery and detonates the central volume. Construction tolerances will be really tight: any asymmetry will result in a fizzle.